# How can I know whether user installed my .apk failed or successed?

Tags: android, installation, apk

Android will send a broadcast if the .apk install successful ,such as replaced,removed and added, but How can I get an message about .apk install failed?

Answer (score 1):

This might help..
ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a report server. It is targeted to android applications developers to help them get data from their applications when they crash or behave erroneously.Check this link for more...
https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try integrating Google new Analytics feature "Firebase Analytics" into your app. Its simple and provides lots of information and Statistics about your App after user installation.
   Its Firebase crashing reports Fatal and Non-Fatal crashes and also provides detailed information such as the device on which the crash occurred, the version of your app, the line number in which the crash happened and also the reason for the crash.

For more reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ refer this documentation.

Comment: It is regretful that our country cant use google service...But Firebase is  a really great tool !

Comment: Are you from China?

Comment: There is this this another great tool to identify crashes called Crashlytics for android https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install . Check if this is of any help to you.

Answer (score 0):

1 use the adb method install the apk

2 do the "adb install ..." in your code

3 return the status result if faile this is return like INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

hope this is useful

Comment: I want to get the result in runtime,so i can try to get the result code as you metioned, is there any posts i can refer to?